# How can I resize the and & or gates or FF in pst-circ package?

Tags: pstricks, scaling, pst-circ

```
\documentclass{exam}  
\usepackage{pst-circ}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{latin}  
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,4)   
 \logicff[inputalabel=$J$,outputb=false,inputblabel=$K$](-3,0){A0}  
 \logicff[inputalabel=$J$,outputb=false,inputblabel=$K$](6,0){A1}  
\logicor[ninputs=2](2,1.2){}  
\logicand[ninputs=2](10,-1){}  
\logicff[inputalabel=$J$,outputb=false,inputblabel=$K$](12,0){A2}  
\psline{-*}(-3,-1)(2,-1)  
\psline{->}(2,-1)(10.5,-1)(10.5,2.3)(12,2.3)  
\end{pspicture}   
\end{latin}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `unit` argument:

```
\logicor[ninputs=2,unit=0.5](2,1.2){}
```